# How to resolve this "required a bean" error

Tags: java, mysql, spring

I am new to Springboot and I learning by Sping's tutorials and guides on "https://spring.io/guides".

Right now I try to understand and redo the tutorial: ["Accessing data with MySQL"](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/)

Unfortunatelly I got the Error during Mavenbuild:

> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
>   2017-12-07 10:26:42.708 ERROR 8100 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :
>
> ---
>
> APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> Field goodRepository in xxx.controller.GoodController required a bean of type 'xxx.repositories.GoodRepository' that could not be found.
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type 'xxx.repositories.GoodRepository' in your configuration.
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Here is my Code:

Good.java:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

import lombok.Data;

@Entity
@Data
public class Good {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    public Good() {
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

GoodRepository:

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import xxx.model.Good;

public interface GoodRepository extends CrudRepository<Good, Long>
{

}
```

GoodController:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import xxx.model.Good;
import xxx.repositories.GoodRepository;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(path="/goods")
public class GoodController {

    @Autowired
    private GoodRepository goodRepository;

    @GetMapping(path="/add")
    public @ResponseBody String addNewGod( @RequestParam String name)
    {
        Good god= new Good();
        god.setName(name);
        goodRepository.save(god);
        return "Saved";
    }

    @GetMapping(path="/all")
    public @ResponseBody Iterable<Good> getAllGods()
    {
        return goodRepository.findAll();
    }

}
```

My application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gccontest
spring.datasource.username=xxx
spring.datasource.password=xxx
```

the mysql-db exists on this port...

What did I where wrong?

Comment: Have you set up your database?

Comment: yes, similar to tutorial. the question ist updated..

Comment: try annotating your repository with `@Repository`

Comment: Unfortunatelly same error.

Is it possible that ist does not find them, because they are in different packeges? "import xxx.model.Good; import xxx.repositories.GoodRepository;"

Comment: Check your application-context.xml, for `component-scan`, check if you've specified the correct path for Spring to scan the beans.

Comment: that is a nice one: I dont have any... find out, it should be under : "src/main/resources/applicationContext.xml". But what should bei written in it? Do you have link/tut?

Comment: If you are using Spring-MVC, you should be having the XML file similar to `***-servlet.xml`, which will have the code similar to `<context:component-scan base-package="com.foo.bar*" />`. Try to find it under `WEB-INF` folder.

Comment: Sorry... no "***-servlet.xml" and no "WEB-INF"-folder
Used "https://start.spring.io/" to initial build with WEB and mysql and others...

Answer (score 0):

You need to annotate your GoodRepository with @Repository.
See the answer from : [Spring Boot Inject CrudRepository into Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36795776/spring-boot-inject-crudrepository-into-service)

```
 @Repository
 public interface GoodRepository extends CrudRepository<Good, Long>{

 }
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly same error.

Is it possible that ist does not find them, because they are in different packeges? "import xxx.model.Good; import xxx.repositories.GoodRepository;"

Answer (score 0):

Mark your GoodRepository implementation class as @service/@component and have a try

Comment: Unfortunatelly same error.

Is it possible that ist does not find them, because they are in different packeges? "import xxx.model.Good; import xxx.repositories.GoodRepository;"

Answer (score 0):

I HAVE FOUND IT!!! ;-)

I have had to edit my Application.java:

```
package xxx;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class })
@ComponentScan({ "xxx.repositories"})
public class Application 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

I did not checked my functionality yet, but it compiles and is runnig! Thank you very much for your tips!!!